# Strange definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

So I have this integral
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{arccot}(\cot(f))\cos(t)\cdot21\,\mathrm df$$
and it's solution in indefinite form is
$$\begin{align}
\int21\cos(t)\mathrm{arccot}(\cot(f))\,\mathrm df &= 21\cos(t)f\mathrm{arccot}(\cot(f)) - \dfrac{21\cos(t)f^2}2 + C \\
&=\dfrac{21\cos(t)f^2}2 + C
\end{align}$$
Strange thing is that if I try to plug in (for the definite integral), $2\pi$ in the not simplified form, i.e.,
$$21\cos(t)f\mathrm{arccot}(\cot(f)) - \dfrac{21\cos(t)f^2}2 + C,$$
I get $\cot(2\pi)$ which is undefined. But if I plug the limits in the simplified form of the indefinite integral, i.e.,
$$\dfrac{21\cos(t)f^2}2 + C,$$I get the result $$42\pi^2\cos(t)$$ So my question is whether the calculator is right by plugging in the limits in the simplified form, and also if it is right, how can I get two different answers for the same definite integral?

Comment: Hi, you can use mathjax to put mathematical formulas right into your question, which makes is more easy to read your question. Please see: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @GambitSquared sorry I will in the future, I just don't know it and don't really have time to learn it at the moment, finals are coming

Answer (score 1):

I would write $$21\cdot \cot(t)\int arccot(\cot(f))df$$ and use integration by parts.

Comment: Why do you need integration by parts? Isn't this simply equivalent to $$21\cos(t)\int f\,\mathrm df$$ which is pretty straight-forward to solve?